# How do you properly position elements in XAML without using absolute position?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a `UWP` app that I am working on, and using `absolute position` creates problems when using the app on screen sizes different than the one it was designed for.

I'm not sure how exactly i should place elements at distances from each other without using `margin` and `absolute position`.    How should I be doing this?

Edit: I am using XAML to design the UI.

Comment: use css-grid. in css-grid there is a property called grid-gap.

Comment: Isn't CSS a completely different markup language? UWP uses xaml.

Comment: ok first thing you have to remove the all margin from the control and set the control to Horizontal and vertical to stretch. and use ColumnDefinition on grid. remove margin form each control. without your xaml code i cant help.

Comment: Hi @LoganStach , This can be very helpful if you can describe your problem more specifically. If you want to know more about XAML layout, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/grid-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what UI you want to build up.
There are various panels and, usually, **there is NO need to use absolute position in most cases**.

Usually, the `Grid` panel is used to create flexible layouts, by adding rows and columns: for example, if you want to create a page with some content and a bottom app bar with buttons on it, you usually create a `Grid` with as many rows as you need for your content controls, plus one for the bottom appbar itself.

Years ago, I also started building UIs by using absolute position for every element, but then times passes and you start having a flexible mind in order to build flexible layouts.

Sorry to not answer any further, but your question is just TOO broad to give any precise answer.

Best regards

Comment: I understand my question is rather broad and I appreciate you answering it.

What I'm confused by is the how I should space apart each element within a stackpanel, grid, etc.  If I put a textblock into a vertical stackpanel and then add another textblock below it, for example, they're going to be right on top of each other.  

I know that in axml you can use DP to add padding to an element, but I don't know of anything like that in UWP aside from margin, which obviously doesn't work.  What should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you properly position elements in XAML without using absolute position?

You should use an appropriate [layout panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels):

> Layout panels are containers that allow you to arrange and group UI elements in your app. The built-in XAML layout panels include `RelativePanel`, `StackPanel`, `Grid`, `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, and `Canvas`.